Windows Service Fails with Error 1053 After Stopping Despite Successful Run: Issue with async/await?
Could someone help me figure out this error with my Windows service project?
I can run this service successfully, it works perfectly but any time the service is stopped it shows this error:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc start EmailAutoResponseService
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

This error is shown AFTER OnStop() is called. I'm assuming it has something to do with my OnStart method and/or the way I'm using async/await.
Could someone please point me in the right direction? Feel free to make other suggestions too, is async/await unnecessary here?
This is my Program.cs file:
https://pastebin.com/h4UhmuZD
And this my EmailAutoResponseService.cs file:
https://pastebin.com/ApAgUXph
These are the relevant methods:
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the EmailAutoResponseService class.
/// </summary>
public EmailAutoResponseService()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LoadDependencies();

    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    LogTs.LogInfo("Running OnStart().");

    Task.Run(async () => await StartServiceAsync());
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    LogTs.LogInfo("Running OnStop().");

    Task.Run(async () => await StopServiceAsync()).Wait();
}

public async Task StartServiceAsync()
{
    LogTs.LogInfo("Running StartServiceAsync().");

    await RunEmailProcessingLoop(_cts.Token);
}

/// <summary>
/// Stops the service asynchronously.
/// </summary>
public async Task StopServiceAsync()
{
    LogTs.LogInfo("Running StopServiceAsync().");
    _cts.Cancel();
    
    // Give some time for the cancellation to be processed
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}


I was accidentally running this service with the ConfigurationHelper.ServiceMode setting set to false. Once I set it to true it worked properly.

The OnStart Method should finish in seconds:

Task _mainloop;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    LogTs.LogInfo("Running OnStart().");

    Task.Run(() => StartService());
}


void StartService()
{
    LogTs.LogInfo("Running StartServiceAsync().");

    _mainloop = RunEmailProcessingLoop(_cts.Token);
}

void StopService()
{
    LogTs.LogInfo("Running StopServiceAsync().");
    _cts.Cancel();
    
    // Wait for the cancellation to be processed
    _mainloop.Wait();
}

Edit RunEmailProcessingLoop accordingly.
